# Method Overloading; Naming Helper Method

Tags: java, overloading, standards

I like creating `public helpers` for `private members` when creating functions.  I made a `public helper`

```
public void create(String key, String value) { ... }
```

for a `private member`

```
private void create(String key, String value) { ... }
```

Now, I am overloading the `private member` and know I need to do so in Java by

- Method signature (type or quantity)

and I am unable to overload by return type.  Thus, I decide to modify my `private member` to accept a boolean argument.

```
private void create(String key, String value, boolean status) { ... }
```

I admit this parameter is not one I plan to use or consider.  Have I become complacent to accept poor coding behavior?

The `public helper` merely calls the `private member` passing supplied arguments

```
public void create(String key, String value) { create(key, value, true); }
```

Comment: not sure that I understand what you are trying to do , can you share the full code ? with what are you trying to overload ?

Comment: "public helper" for "private member"? Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: You can't overload by return type because it's not part of the function signature.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type

Comment: Do both "create" methods do both have the same logic? If they differ in logic, why not using different names that would reflect their different behavior?

Comment: @T.C. Correct; corrected

Comment: @Dariusz No; Helper is intended to hide or abstract the `private member` functionality - i.e. public member calls private with supplied arguments  and nothing more.

Comment: @Vulcan Go back and read my question

Comment: @TrippKinetics Go back and read my question

Comment: Why don't you just name the private method createImpl?

Comment: @AmirAfghani I am trying to ascertain if doing what I wrote above is good behavior or even worth the effort as compared to what you suggest.

Comment: what about using an interface? Exposed methods would be public by default and the private methods can stay, well, private

Comment: If all one method does is call the other, what is the point? If you could do it, you would be doing exactly the same thing as making the private method public (apart from adding the overhead of another method call until it's optimised out). You're not improving encapsulation or abstraction in any way. And to answer the question, yes, adding a parameter that does nothing just to allow you to override an identically-named method would be bad. Using a different name would be better if you really want to do it. E.g. @AmirAfghani's suggestion, or some people use things like `_create`

Comment: @Mushy Let me ask this way: why do you have two different "create" methods? If both methods do the same, and the only difference is that one returns a value and the second one - don't - consider using Optional (Java 8 or Guava). Otherwise, rename the second method. Using an artificial parameter sounds like a bad design and definitely decreases code readability.

Comment: @CupawnTae What I thought but I wanted the opinion of others.

Comment: @Dariusz I was lazy and wanted to encapsulate functionality of create in private method while only allowing public visibility of the function call.  I had an idea this was subject or questionable coding but needed my hand slapped to be certain.

Comment: I still don't get what encapsulation you're trying to achieve. By making a method private, you aren't encapsulating anything, you are just not allowing that method to be accessed (directly) outside that class. By creating a public method that does nothing else but call the private method, you are removing that protection and are in exactly the same situation as if the private method were public. There is no encapsulation here. Now if your public method did something else as well as calling the private one that's different, but then it would have different logic and should be named differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a helper class might be a quick solution, you are still coupling the implementation to the classes you are exposing (the "caller" class).  Interfaces were created to create the abstraction you intend to create (i.e. hiding private implementation from public view) but the added flexibility that:

1. Could be used by other classes wanting to have their own implementations of similar behaviour
2. De-couples the implementation from the calling class.
3. At run-time you could choose which implementation to use (via IoC or similar)

Here's my suggestion:

**MyObjectImpl.java** -> implements MyObject.java

```
private Object createObjectNotInitialized( String name ){
   return new Object();
}

private Object createObjectInitialized( String name ){
  Object newObj = new Object();
  newObj.setName( name );
  return newObj;
}

public Object createObject( String name, boolean doInit ){
  if( doInit ){
     return createObjectInitialized(name);
  }else{
     return createObjectNotInitialized(name);
  }
}

// you can chose to init objects by default - I chose not to for this example
public Object createObject( String name ){
     return createObjectNotInitialized(name);
}
```

**MyObject.java** -> Interface

```
Object createObject( String name, boolean doInit );
Object createObject( String name );
```

**Caller.java** Calling Class

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObjectImpl();
Object o = myObj.createObject( "Hello" );
```