# Why I need different return types, when overloading generic methods

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Below is the sample code, which is confusing me on how java method    overloading works in case of generics.

**Question is :** why do I need to have different return types in case I overload method with generics parameters ?

I know that erasure remove `<T>` and all I have is List and it will be ambiguous for compiler, but how different return type help in deciding which method to call ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {       
        PracticeGenerics p = new PracticeGenerics();
        p.test();
    }



private void test() throws Exception {
        //print(null); //The method print(List<String>) is ambiguous for the type PracticeGenerics
        print(new LinkedList<String>());
        print(new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }


public String print(List<String> list){
        System.out.println("print string");
        return null;
    }

    public Object print(List<Integer> list){
        System.out.println("print Integer");
        return null;
    }
```

Java Version on my machine:

java version "1.6.0_31"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: why don't you just rename the methods to `printIntegerList` and `printStringList`, so that there is no ambiguity as to which method is being called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a method's signature in Java include its return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type)

Comment: Not sure I get your question. Having different return types is *not* sufficient to get that code to compile. Also, your code example includes a commented-out section about passing null values - is that relevant at all to your question?

Comment: Yes that can be done, but code is still compiling & calling the correct method, by just changing the return type.
I want to know, how return type helps compiler to avoid ambiguity?

In other words, this code won't compile if return type is same.

Comment: @Duncan: Actually, it is. Just tested it. Of course you need `import java.util.*;

public class PracticeGenerics {
` at the top of the file and `}` at the bottom

Comment: @Mohit Which compiler are you using? I've tried both Eclipse and  `javac` for Java 8 and it refuses to compile your code.

Comment: The title of this question is very confusing "why do I need different return types".  A: You don't and even having different return types (like your sample) will not allow the code to compile.  The problem is with your parameters, not the return types.

Comment: Interesting - mine fails to compile in Eclipse too.

Comment: BTW, tested it with javac 1.6.0-internal

Comment: I think the problem is with Eclipse. The IDE seems to test the return type when checking erasure when Generics are involved but the basic Java compiler will only check for names and parameter. This might be a call for bug report

Comment: javac 1.7.0_21 doesn't compile it, though - seems like a bug/feature in some compilers allow compilation of that code

Comment: I haved updated question with my java version. Can't believe this is a bug. But it has to be if its failing in 1.7
Though its still working from cmd for me

Comment: This code will never compile. Method dispatch uses name and parameter types only. If the code seems to run then you are likely using a previously compiled version of the class. I know that when code fails to compile the old version of the class is left untouched. Attempting the run the program will mean running the old code and not the new. I suggest deleting all class files and trying again or running `javap PracticeGenerics.class` to see what the contents of the class actually looks like.

Comment: As far as I know: it was a Bug in Java 1.6 which couldn't detect problems with method signatures due to the type erasure. This page might be interessting, because it addresses the same bug and provides some bug report links: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074534/core-java/netbeans-7-1-s-internal-compiler-and-jdk-6-respecting-return-type-for-method-overloading.html

Comment: @ortis I don't think it has something to do with the used IDE.

Comment: Great now question has been given a -1. The person who has done this can he discuss about it here. You just can't give -1 if you don't understand it....

Answer (score 2):

Overloading, simply said, means to have two or more methods **with the same name** but **with a different signature**.

The signature of a method consists of the methods name and the parameters. When overloading methods, obviously the names will be the same, which means that the overloaded methods **differ only with the parameters list** they have.

The return-type has nothing to do with method overloading!

Comment: I also had the same understanding, but now i have bumped in to this issue... I hope someone can confirm this as a bug or lets wait for anyone with some extra information.