# Getting Method Signatures from Java Files with Select-String and a regex

Tags: java, regex, spring, powershell

the project i work on at the moment is a restful Webbackend. I use Spring MVC for this.

However i want to use powershell to generate a small documentation of the rest api. I want to give this to the frontend developer. He is not a java gui, so i don't want to just throw a java doc at his feet.

So to cut a long story short. I'm trying to write script, that looks for my controller files, and reads the signatures of methods which are annotated with @RequestMapping...

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<AccountIF> getAll() {
  return service.getAll();
}
```

I'm able to read the line with the @ pretty easily. But when i try to get both lines with an regex, i get nothing.

This is what i have so far:

```
ls -r -i *Controller.java | Select-String -Pattern '@RequestMapping.+\n\t+.+'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match: there is no `newline` + `tab` characters in your method.

> @RequestMapping.+**\n\t+.+**

Assuming that you want to get every [method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16149445/4424236) decorated with `@RequestMapping` this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\*Controller.java' | Get-Content -Raw | ForEach-Object {
    [regex]::Matches($_, '\s*(@RequestMapping.+\))\s+(.+\))').Value.Trim()
}
```

**P.S.** On a side note, it seems that `Select-String` is processing file line-by-line, so multiline regex wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: What about just this: `'(?s)@RequestMapping.+?\{'`

Comment: @AKS That should work too, I'm just extracting strings separately so they can be easier to process later, if needed.