# Why method overloading is not able to resolve by return type in java

Tags: java, overloading

Method overloading is based on the method signature. But when we make it clear by the return type that which method needs to be called, why Java is not able to figure this out? The sample code is below.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = new TestClass().getI(5);       //line 3

        String t = new TestClass().getI(3);    //line 5
    }

    public int getI(int i){  //Line 8
        return 1;
    }

    public String getI(int i){  //Line 12
        return "ss";
    }
}
```

Here we can see that in line 3 we are expecting a return type as integer. So it is evident that we want to call the method at line 8. In line 5, it is evident that we want to invoke method at line 12. But Java is not able to handle it and on execution gives Error. I needed to understand why Java is not able to figure out this simple scenario?

Comment: because the return type is not part of the method signature. As a result you get the compiler error.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type

Comment: Method overloading works with different amount and types of arguments, this has nothing to do with the return type.