# Determine what a method signature would be for a given call

Tags: java

I'm still pretty new to java and I'm having a hard time understanding some of the things. I understand this is not code but I'm trying to answer my study guide for class and I have come across two questions that I cannot seem to understand. I understand that to write a method signature: you need an access modifier, return type, method name, and parameters but I am lost when there are multiple types. Thanks.

Determine what a method signature would be for a given call -

```
b. String s = “a phrase”; int x = getLength(s);

c. double pi = 3.14159;
float radius = 42;
double area = getArea(radius, pi);
```

Comment: `public double getArea(float radius, double pi)` - Access specifier can change as per the method declaration actually

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).  There are some good examples there.

Comment: It's not possible to say given the information provided: it depends on the signatures of methods visible in scope.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer technically, the return type and access modifiers are not [part of the method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2).

Comment: if you are calling from the main method you would have to add "static"

Comment: read up! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type