# Kotlin type erasure - why are functions differing only in generic type compilable while those only differing in return type are not?

Tags: kotlin, type-erasure

While working on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653302/6202869) of [How does erasure work in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42916801/6202869) I found out some things I did not yet understand, nor did I find any sources why it is that way.

Why is the following not compilable?

```
fun bar(foo: List<*>) = ""
fun bar(foo: List<*>) = 2
```

while the following is?

```
fun bar(foo: List<String>) = ""
fun bar(foo: List<Int>) = 2
```

For me it even gets more curious, when adding a generic type that isn't even used, i.e. the following compiles too:

```
fun bar(foo: List<*>) = ""
fun <T> bar(foo: List<*>) = 2 // T isn't even used
```

As the last one doesn't even use `T` and as we know, generics are erased at runtime, why does this one work, while the variant without generic type does not?

Within the byte code methods only differing in return type are allowed (already described in the [above linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653302/6202869)).

Any hints, sources and/or references are welcome.

Added [this question now also at discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-type-erasure-why-are-functions-differing-only-in-generic-type-compilable-while-those-only-differing-in-return-type-are-not/9265).

Comment: Have you tried asking on official forums? Personally I think first not compiling is correct. Even though it would be possible to map it to jvm, It's best to avoid any confusion at compile time - hence why it's not allowed.

Comment: Not yet... is the next I will do... but the last question I asked didn't get that much response too... lets see... Regarding "it's best to avoid any confusion at compile time"... how is the usage of the generic types not confusing... I mean in that particular case  ;-)

Comment: You expect the list to get `bar`-ed regardless of lists type. If it does something else it shouldn't be called the same so it's in no way confusing.

Comment: @Pawel this is *not* the point, of course renaming them would work. this question is not a about a potential problem resolution per-se, that I am sure the OP is aware of anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why these functions compile or don't compile is related to Kotlin's overload resolution rules. Kotlin does not use the expected type for resolving overloads, so when you call this function:

```
 val x = bar(listOf(""))
```

...there is no way for the Kotlin compiler to determine the type, and it does not allow you to disambiguate the call by specifying the type of `x` explicitly.

In the second case, there is no overload resolution problem because the functions have distinct parameter types, and there is no JVM name conflict problem because the functions have different return types (and thus different erased signatures). Therefore, the code compiles.

Comment: now I got it... thanks... that hint regarding the explicit specification of the type has solved the knot.

Comment: do you have a reference to the overload resolution rules? or other technical papers? Or which sources should be followed for inner workings of Kotlin? For Java we have the JLS... what is there for Kotlin?

Comment: maybe a question for its own... it can't possibly be [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-spec) as there are way too much TODOs in there ;-)

Comment: There's [this document](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/NameResolution.adoc). The spec is indeed a work in progress.

Comment: @yole a follow-up question if you don't mind, what about type erasure in this case? suppose I compile those two methods (and kotlin has type erasure) and try to use those compiled methods. this would work `val x = emptyList<Int>();
    val ss = bar(x);`, my question is how? since you obviously can't call these from java

Comment: @Eugene regarding your first sample and assuming the first compilable sample of the question: it works, because you pass a `List<Int>`. The kotlin compiler knows that it must be `bar(foo: List<Int>)` what you are calling and will setup everything accordingly. The byte code then shows that the return type is `String`. Type erasure is taking place but just after the compiler did its work to ensure that the code isn't ambiguous... same goes for the second compilable variant. As long as you do not specify the generic type directly, the kotlin compiler knows that you wanted to call the first method

Comment: so summarizing: it was a deliberate design decision that specifying the type on `x` will not influence which method is the one to be called but rather the other way around. The called method (with or without generic information) influences the type being returned. Are there any plans to have something like a "Kotlin only"-JVM-variant? I mean: if I decide that my code will never be called from Java, the `@Jvm`-annotations wouldn't be needed anymore, right? Maybe to overcome name clashes a convention must take place (and be applied under the hood), but that should be doable, right? ;-)