# Why doesn't this overload?

Tags: java, kotlin, overloading, type-inference, overload-resolution

Writing on a Jooq helper class. (More business-specific methods to be added as soon as I've figured this out ...)

```
import org.jooq.*
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Provider

/**A helper class facilitating database manipulations.
 * Uses jOOQ for its manipulations.
 * Relies on the application context being properly initialized s.t. Spring creates and injects the correct
 * [DSLContext].*/
@Repository
class DatabaseManipulator{

    private val provider: Provider<DSLContext>
    private val create:DSLContext
        get() = provider.get()

    @Inject
    constructor(provider: Provider<DSLContext>) {
        this.provider = provider
    }


    /**Executes non-[Select]-type SQL queries on the database.
     * Does not perform any kind of checks and trusts the client to know what they're doing.
     * @param query the query to be executed.
     *
     * @return depending on the type of the [query]:
     *      <ul>
     *      <li> Delete : the number of deleted records</li>
     *      <li> Insert : the number of inserted records</li>
     *      <li> Merge : result may be meaningless</li>
     *      <li> Truncate : result may be meaningless</li>
     *      <li> Update : the number of updated records</li>
     *      </ul>
     */
    fun execute(query:DSLContext.()-> Query):Int{
        return create.query().execute()
    }

    /**Executes [Select]-type [query] and returns its result*/
    fun <T:Record> execute(query:DSLContext.()->Select<T>):Result<T>{
        return create.query().fetch()
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Now let's add some tests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class DatabaseManipulatorIT {

    @Inject
    private lateinit var manipulate:DatabaseManipulator

    @Inject
    private lateinit var em:EntityManager

    @Test
    fun executeSelectQuery() {
        //given
        val expectedNumberOfOrganizations = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT (o) FROM Organization o")
            .singleResult as Long

        //when
        val reportedNumberOfOrganizations = manipulate.execute {
            selectCount().from(ORGANIZATION)
        }.first().value1().toLong()

        //then
        assertThat(reportedNumberOfOrganizations).isEqualTo(expectedNumberOfOrganizations)
    }

    @Test
    fun executeNonSelectQuery() {
        //given
        val expectedNumberOfDeletions = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT COUNT (o) FROM Organization o WHERE o.usageCreditLimited = true"
        ).singleResult as Long

        //when
        val actualNumberOfDeletions = manipulate.execute {(
            deleteFrom(ORGANIZATION)
                .where(ORGANIZATION.USAGECREDITLIMITED.eq(true))
            ) as Query
        }

        //then
        assertThat(actualNumberOfDeletions).isEqualTo(expectedNumberOfDeletions)

    }
}
```

That fails to compile because

```
Error:(50, 50) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <T : Record> execute(query: DSLContext.() -> Select<T>): Result<T>
cannot be applied to
(DSLContext.() -> DeleteConditionStep<OrganizationRecord!>!)
Error:(50, 58) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is DSLContext.() -> DeleteConditionStep<OrganizationRecord!>! but DSLContext.() -> Select<???> was expected
```

No shit, I don't *want* you to use that method, I want you to use the *other*.

Let's try making that explicit:

```
//when
val actualNumberOfDeletions = manipulate.execute {(
    deleteFrom(ORGANIZATION)
        .where(ORGANIZATION.USAGECREDITLIMITED.eq(true))
    ) as Query
}
```

still fails to compile the second test case because

```
Error:(50, 50) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <T : Record> execute(query: DSLContext.() -> Select<T>): Result<T>
cannot be applied to
(DSLContext.() -> Query)
Error:(50, 58) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is DSLContext.() -> Query but DSLContext.() -> Select<???> was expected
```

How do I get Kotlin to call the correct method?

Comment: The `Select` is essentially a `Query` so the method you want to use cannot be resolved correctly. Try to change the method signature so it does't depend on the passed argument to resolve the method.

Comment: @KeivanEsbati could you elaborate on "so the method you want to use cannot be resolved correctly"? I can see that that's the case, I'd prefer to understand WHY it is the case. Even if `Select` is a `Query`, the reverse doesn't hold true. So why aren't the non-`Select` queries bound to the non-`Select` method?

Comment: I added a reference and post it as an answer so you can read a little more about it if you like.

Comment: jOOQ distinguishes between `fetch` (produces a result) and `execute` (produces an update count). Why do you want to use the same term for both, instead? At some point, overloading is a much bigger source of pain than convenience... Note, you probably want to reference `ResultQuery<T>` instead of `Select<T>` for a more generic solution.

Comment: if you extract your code into its own function, e.g. `fun q() : DSLContext.() -> Query = { ... }` or `fun s() : DSLContext.() -> Select` and pass those functions to your `execute` it will (probably) work (not yet tested)... probably even the following could work: `fun <T> dsl(dsl : DSLContext.() -> T) = dsl` and call `manipulate.execute(dsl { ... })`... does it work? ;-) Maybe you will sooner or later end up here: [How does type erasure work in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916801) or here: [Kotlin type erasure - ... generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092214)

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` is essentially `Query` so the method you want to use cannot be inferred correctly.

> The compiler resolves everything about the method invocation without paying any attention to the generic constraints involved until the very last moment – where it notices that the chosen method isn’t valid, and fails with an error.

This problem occur with **generics**, the compiler recognize the methods as two different method but when trying to resolve the method it may not find the correct method based on available data. If you want to know why check this article, [Overloading and Generic constraints](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/) by Jon Skeet.