# Method overloading with type erasure

Tags: java, generics, overloading, type-erasure

In the book "Java Generics and Collections" by Maurice Naftalin & Philip Wadler there is a code related to method overloading with type erasure on page 56. 
It says that just like two methods with the same signature is not allowed, also we cannot have two distinct methods with the same type erasure. Then it goes on and gives a simple class to demonstrate a working code:

```
class Overload{
  public static int sum(List<Integer> ints){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i: ints) sum += i;
    return sum
  }
  public static String sum(List<String> strs){
    StringBuffer sum = new StringBuffer();
    for(String s: strings) sum.append(s);
    return sum.toString();
  }
}

assert sum(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)) == 6; //ok
assert sum(Arrays.asList("a", "b")).equals("ab"); //ok
```

Then the erasures of the two `sum` methods are given as

```
int sum(List)
String sum(List)
```

Basically, the authors write that, since they have different return types, Java can distinguish them and it's ok.
However, as far as I know return type of a method is not part of a method signature and is irrelevant when it comes to overloading. I've also tested this code on Java 8 and compiler error is thrown. My question is, did the author make a mistake with this statement or was this code permitted in the older versions of Java?

Comment: The authors made a mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type/25091733

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is correct in terms of the JVM, where the return type can determine which method you call (we have one `I(Ljava.util.List;)` and one `Ljava.lang.String;(Ljava.util.List;)`; they are different, but notice that erasure has already happened), but it is wrong in terms of the Java language. Indeed, this fact makes `javac`'s life harder, because it often needs to create bridges for generic methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mistake in the text book.  It has been acknowledged by the authors and (according to the errata page) corrected:

- http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596527754

**UPDATE** - actually, I'm not sure that I picked the right erratum.  The page numbers (page 50) don't match with the one that you are talking about.   But if you flip to the "unconfirmed errata" tab, there is already one for page 56.

Anyway, the meta-point remains.  Reputable textbook publishers maintain errata pages, and they are a good place to look if you need clarification of an apparent mistake.

Comment: Thanks, It is what I was looking for. I didn't know about errata. I'll check them

Comment: Actually, It is stated in the unconfirmed errata section in the give link