# Why non-static method can not be referenced ONLY sometimes?

Tags: java, generics, static

I have encountered a rather strange compiler behaviour: the non-static method could be referenced from static context, but not always.
My understanding is that

```
void method() {}
```

and

```
void static method(ThisClassName c) {}
```

should have the same signature inside the JVM and hence their references should behave the same, but apparently I am wrong.

Here is my example:

Parent:

```
package com.example;

abstract class Parent<S> {
    abstract void doSomething(final S s);
}
```

Child:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

class Child extends Parent<String> {
    // This line compiles OK
    private static BiConsumer<Child, String> consumer1 = Child::doSomething;
    // Compiler error: "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context."
    private static BiConsumer<Parent, String> consumer2 = Child::doSomething;
    // This line compiles OK
    private static BiConsumer<Parent, String> consumer3 = Child::doSomethingElse;

    @Override
    void doSomething(final String s) {
        // do something
    }

    static void doSomethingElse(final Parent<String> c, final String s) {
        // do something else
    }

}
```

The problem here is that consumer2 can not be set due to a compiler error.

How I came across this: I needed to pass the

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<Parent, ?>>
```

around and the map itself was built only once (at startup) thus it made sense to make it static final.

Comment: *"...should have the same signature inside the JVM and hence their references should behave the same..."* What would make you think that? It's not remotely correct.

Comment: Read about the meaning of [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder both methods take a single argument, of the same type (assuming that the first methods is defined in the class ThisClassName). What exactly is incorrect here?

Comment: @LuCio thanks! It's sad to see that the return time is not included into the signature, but that doesn't seem to be applicable here. So I think that my expectation (static methods taking class instance being equivalent to non-static methods) was (and still is) correct.

To clarify: I have seen the answer below and I think I understand now what went wrong.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov I'm not sure I can follow you. Your code shows static methods which have other signatures than the instance (non-static) methods. There is no ambiguity between them.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov - The implicit `this` parameter for an instance method is not the same as an explicit parent-class parameter of a `static` method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the words you quoted were about the method() example above.
I should have wrote it like this to avoid misunderstanding:
class AClass {
void method1() {}
void static method2(AClass c) {}
}
The signatures of these two methods (in my understanding) are the same.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov - No, they aren't. One is an instance method with no parameters (and an implicit `this` parameter), the other is a static method with an explicit `AClass` parameter. Those are different signatures. The implicit `this` on instance methods isn't just a leading class-typed parameter on a `static`. (There's some *conceptual* similarity, but that's it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you please share a link backing up this claim?

This is what I was able to find:

"Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html
Wikipedia seems to say the same about Java.

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov - How about [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)? :-) *"Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types."* `this` is not a formal parameter. It's a *receiver parameter* ([§8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)), which is expressly not a formal parameter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a case of poor compiler error reporting. Using my compiler (Eclipse) I instead get the error:

> The type Child does not define doSomething(Parent, String) that is applicable here

And indeed it does not, as an instance method has an implicit receiver argument (`this`), which for `Child::doSomething` has the type `Child`, so `BiConsumer<Parent, String>` is not a compatible target type.

You could use a reference to `Parent`'s version of `doSomething` instead:

```
private static BiConsumer<Parent, String> consumer2 = Parent::doSomething;
```