# We can override method by changing return type (Covariant Return Type) in Java. Why?

Tags: java, oop

It is not possible to overload method by changing return type in Java, But we can override method by changing return type (Covariant Return Type). **Why**?

More specifically, JVM uses full signature of a method for lookup/resolution. Full signature means it includes return type in addition to argument types. i.e., a class can have two or more methods differing only by return type. javac uses this fact to implement covariant return types.

So why can't we overload a method using covariant return type?

Comment: For your question about overloading, I believe that the Java interpreter only "sees" the method name and number/type of arguments, not the return type.  So two methods with identical signatures only differing in return type look the same.  For the second half of your question, the return type of an overriden cannot be changed willy-nilly.  It either has to match the type in the interface _or_ be more specific than that type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The JLS doesn't mandate a stack based virtual machine. The JVMS does.

Comment: for the why -- If the Java did not allow covariant return type for overridden methods, then that would compromising on inheritance characteristics, I think this is the reason why designers might have thought like this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  JVM uses full signature of a method for lookup/resolution, so why it can not distinguish two methods with different return types.

Comment: I might be wrong, but my understanding is that when the JVM goes to call a method, it can only use the name and number/types of parameters to figure out which version to call.  If two methods only are different with regard to the return type, it would be impossible for the JVM to figure out which version to call.

Comment: @Rookie007 may be that is the reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  got it.

Comment: The duplicate for the other part of the question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149285/does-a-methods-signature-in-java-include-its-return-type (in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/33050402/477420 is the same as accepted answer here)

Comment: @PrinceKumar I don't understand your comment - I based my suggestion on accepted answer to *this question*. Clearly you've accepted answer that is essentially identical to one I've linked to... So despite the question talking about covariance  it looks like you are only looking for "why return type is not part of the signature in Java"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer might sound naive but I think doing so would confuse the compiler that which function are you trying to use, if you are not using the return value of function call.

```
int foo(int a, int b) {...}

double foo(int a, int b) {...}

// calling one of the function and not using return value
foo(3,4);
```

Compiler when generates class files, it has complete method signature (including return type & package name as well) in compiled files to uniquely identify the exact function. If overloading is allowed with different return types the compiler will get confused to decide which function is being used, provided you are not using the return value.