# If the return type is not a part of method signature in Java, why must an overriding method have the same as its parent?

Tags: java, oop, overriding

Is there any particular reason why Java does not allow method overriding by changing the return type of a sub-class?

Since the return type is not part of the method signature, isn't it the case that a method having a different return types (but having the same name and the same number and type of parameters) are seen as the *same* by the compiler?

Comment: I've always thought that the return type was part of the method signature. Am I wrong?

Comment: It isn't. Return type isn't part of the method signature. This must be true at least in the case of Java I guess.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: The return type is always part of the signature.

Comment: No it's not. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16149445/13602601

Comment: It works perfectly fine to replace the return type by a sub type in an overriding method. Just try it with an example (and post it if it does not work).

Comment: Additionally: The reason that you cannot override the return type with any type is that every polymorphic use of the method depends on a certain return type. A subtype shares the same interface as the non-overriden type, so it is ok. Using other types than subtypes in the return type is rejected. If you do not understand it immediately extend your post with an example, it will be explained easier then.

Answer (score 2):

#### My understanding

Java Language Specification does not consider return type as method signature.

Since return type is not present in signature, two methods can't differ only by return type(as they will be ambiguous to runtime). So compiler will not allow it.

This can be considered along the same lines of type erasure of generic parameters. Since type will not be available at runtime, compiler will block any two methods whose signature(parameters) vary only by generic type to avoid ambiguity at runtime.

Similarly, exceptions are not considered in method signature and hence two methods can not just vary by exceptions. Compiler will not allow it.

Similarly, access modifiers are not considered in method signature and hence two methods can not just vary by access modifiers. Compiler will not allow it.

So the basis is, two methods can not vary only by components that are not part of method signature.

Basically compilers are meant to parse the program according to JLS grammar and block anything that does not follow the grammar. Compilers do have luxury to accommodate some deviations. Still it will not outright allow a violation.

All these are done to ensure that the runtime can execute more freely with high confidence based on the output of compiler.

### References

> Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.

Ref: [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.

Ref: [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the return types are reference types. The notion of return-type-substitutability supports covariant returns, that is, the specialization of the return type to a subtype.

```
If R1 is void then R2 is void.

If R1 is a primitive type, then R2 is identical to R1.

If R1 is a reference type then:

R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or

R1 = |R2|
```

Ref: [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)

Comment: Overriding is redefining the method in a subclass. This means that the new method replaces the inherited one - the collision is resolved by choosing the subclass definition.

Comment: Ah 8.4.5! I've been looking at the wrong sections of the spec - 8.4.2 and 8.4.8.1 - and was confused why the spec doesn't mention this at all.

Comment: @CoronA, practically yes. Please try this: `public class OverrideTest {  public static void main(String[] args) {  A a = new A();  System.out.println(a.override().m2());  } }  class A {  private int m() {  System.out.println("base m");  return 1;  }   int m2() {  System.out.println("base m2");  return m();  }   A override() {  return new A() {  public int m() {  System.out.println("override m");  return super.m();  }   public int m2() {  System.out.println("override m2");  return m();  }  };  } }`

Comment: @Sweeper Glad to be of help

Comment: One cannot change the return type of an overridden method to something other than a subtype of the original return (this is part of your explanation). I only added my comment because you mentioned "Since return type is not present in signature, two methods can't differ only by return type(as they will be ambiguous to runtime). So compiler will not allow it". But overrding `public Object m()` with `public String m()` is perfectly legal. This sound contradictory to me.

Comment: @CoronA yes that is co-variance